# Using TweenMax in Angular2 project

Tags: typescript, npm, angular, gsap, angular-cli

How can I setup TweenMax in my Angular2 project. Instead of adding the script in my HTML I want to be able to import TweenMax similar to this:

```
import { TweenMax } from 'gsap';
```

NOTE: I'm using angular-cli.

Answer (score 6):

Adding **this** external package to angular 2 is almost the same like any other package out there. jquery, firebase, you name it..

But you should know that at this moment, there are no typings file for the gsap module. So you can't cherry pick the imports however you want. This also means no intelisense in typescript :( But you can still use it like this:

**Step 1:** npm install it

```
npm install gsap --save
```

**Step 2:** prevent typescript for complaining about not finding the clases by adding the following line to `typings.d.ts` file:

```
declare var module: { id: string };

declare let TimelineMax: any; // declare it as any.
 // so no error complains, Typescript compiler is happy now:)
```

Once the typings file are created for this module step 4 becomes:

```
typings install gsap --save. After that make sure you have included: /// <reference path="../typings/path to your gsap typings" />
```

**Step 3:** use it in your component - for example in `app.component.ts`:

```
import 'gsap' // this is required for TimelineMax() to work
// decorator stuff here.
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  ngOnInit(){

    let targetObject = document.getElementByTagName('h1');

    let tl = TimelineMax(); // this is free of errors now

    tl.from(targetObject, 1, { x:400 });
    tl.play();
  }
}
```

**Step 4:** in this setup, there is no need to add anything to the main.ts (bootstrap file) so enjoy!

Comment: Hey since angular-cli files are changed, can you update the answer? for an example, step2 and step3 are not there anymore. 
PS - I've been looking for solutions for my error and came across this. https://github.com/greensock/GreenSock-JS/issues/228

Comment: @Saiyaff Farouk thank you for telling me :) Can you please verify that now is ok? I don't work with angular anymore. I'm using `elm` for almost everything now. I've gotten a bit rusty on angular :)

Comment: Could you help me what to do with Angular 1 ?

Answer (score 6):

There is an easier way
just

```
npm install --save-dev gsap
npm install --save-dev @types/gsap
```

in your ts file, import gsap

```
import {TweenLite} from "gsap";
```

and in your method or on ngOnInit you can write

```
let photo = document.getElementById("photo");
TweenLite.to(photo, 2, {width:"200px", height:"550px"});
```

if you have a div with and ID of photo

Comment: When I do that `TweenLite` is undefined, any idea?

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: @types/gsap works perfect, all methods recognized, thanks! (angular 5.2.9)

Answer (score 0):

Beside adding type definition for gsap, try:

- running it outside Angular Zone
- assign an instance with `this`

like so:

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import {TweenMax} from "gsap";

myTween: any;

constructor( private ngZone: NgZone ){}

ngOnInit() {

    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => 
      {
        this.tween = TweenMax;
        this.tween.to( some params ); // do your stuff
      }
    );
}
```

Note: Tested on Angular 5.2.4 / Cli: 1.6.8 / typescript: 2.53